# How can I add jQuery information to a html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This html form gets displayed by a bit of javascript code. Now I want to add the information of the cells in my table, when I click on them, to this kind of alert.

How can I do that?

```
<div class='alertBox' id='box'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tableBody td').on('click', function() {
            alert($(this).html() + ' ' + months[currentMonth] + ' ' + currentYear);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <form>
        <input name='Event' type='text' value='Event'> <br>
    </form>

    <a onclick='unpop()' class='close'>Close</a>
</div>
...
```

This is a website, where you can add appointments to a calendar and afterwards the appointments will be displayed by a raspberry pi.

Comment: Hi Max - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more I can help with, please add a comment below my answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. *(You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question.)* Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answer. 
I already found another solution.
Here it is if you are interested:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tableBody td').on('click', function() {
        var cellIndex = document.getElementById('displayDate').innerHTML = $(this).text() + ' ' + months[currentMonth] + ' ' + currentYear;
    });
});

function pop() {
    document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'block';
    cellIndex;
}

function unpop() {
    document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution! +1

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML for the alert box is added by javascript, then you will need to use `.on()` to catch user events (this is called [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)). Also, when you do that, you must attach the `.on()` method to an element that definitely exists before the javascript is run - `$(document)` is always safe.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#tableBody td', function() {
    let txt = $(this).text();
    $('#box input[name=Event]').val(txt);
    $('#box').show();
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '#box a.close', function(){
    $('#box').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
th,td{border:1px solid #ccc;}

#box{position:absolute;top:5vh;left:20vw;padding:2vh;background:wheat;display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='alertBox' id='box'>
  <form>
    <input name='Event' type='text' value='Event'> <br>
  </form>
  <a class='close'>Close</a>
</div>

<table>
  <thead><th>Name</th><th>Vehicle</th></thead>
  <tbody id="tableBody">
    <tr><td>Bob</td><td>Car</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sam</td><td>Truck</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Fred</td><td>Bike</td></tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

Comment: `body` is undefined

Comment: That should do it